# 管理サイトにおけるAPIの認証について

Tags: javascript, security

現在あるサービスの管理サイトを作成しようと考えています。
この管理サイトはJavaScriptのSPAで構築しようとしています。以下にサービスの概要を書きます。

バックエンドのAppサーバ
ドメイン: backend.example.com
サーバ仕様: JSONによりデータベースに変更を加えたりデータを取得したりする。

管理サイトのAppサーバ
ドメイン: admin.example.com
サーバ仕様: 上記のバックエンドサーバのAPIを呼び出すことによってデータを追加したり閲覧したりする。

管理サイトはBasic Authでエントリーページとなるindex.htmlは認証できますが、JavascriptAPIの認証はどのように実装すればいいのでしょうか。